# Can I create a for loop containing multiple type declarations?

Tags: c++

For example:

Is there anything I can do, that might allow me to do this:

```
for(TiXmlElement * pChild = elem->First(), int i=0; // note multiple type declarations
    pChild; 
    pChild=pChild->NextSiblingElement(), i++) // note multiple types
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Perhaps there is a `boost` header?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope.

If you want to limit the scope of variables to the loop just add another scope:

```
{
    TiXmlElement * pChild = elem->First();
    int i = 0;
    for(; pChild; pChild=pChild->NextSiblingElement(), i++)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Blocks do not have to be attached to functions or conditionals. You can surround any piece of code with a block to limit the scope of temporary variables to that block.

```
{
    TiXmlElement * pChild;
    int i;
    for ( pChild = elem->First(), i = 0;
          pChild;
          pChild = pChild->NextSiblingElement(), ++i )
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since C++17, introducing multiple variables is possible with [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding):

```
// multiple type declarations
for (auto [pChild, i] = std::tie(elem->First(), 0); pChild; pChild = pChild->NextSiblingElement(), ++i) {
    // ...
}
```

`pChild` is a `TiXmlElement*`, and `i` is an `int`, as expected.